# Send Multiple data with ajax

Tags: ajax, jsp

I want to use ajax for add data in database and i found following code in net and it is working fine.

```
<script language='javascript'>
reqObj=null;
function saveCust(){
    document.getElementById('res').innerHTML='processing';
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        reqObj=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else {
        reqObj=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }
    reqObj.onreadystatechange=processSave;
    reqObj.open('POST','./custSave?reqObj.open('POST','./cName?id='+document.getElementById('CustCode').value,true);,true);
    reqObj.send(null);
}
function processSave(){
    if(reqObj.readyState==4){
        document.getElementById('res').innerHTML=reqObj.responseText;
    }
}
</script>
```

Above code sends only one String but, i have 5 Strings in my form.

Please anybody alter the code for sending multiple data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're sending a single parameter in the `reqObj.open` function:

```
reqObj.open('POST','./custSave?reqObj.open('POST','./cName?id='+document.getElementById('CustCode').value,true);,true);
```

Note that the only parameter you send is `id`.

You can add more parameters in the flavor of QueryString:

```
id=something&otherParameter=else //and more parameters
```

---

IMO the easiest way to handle an ajax request would be using jQuery, as shown and heavily explained by BalusC in [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4112686/1065197).

Based on the samples there and [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5004233/1065197), you can come with the following code:

- Assuming the 5 Strings are in the form

  ```
  function saveCust(){
      $('#res').html('processing');
      var $form = $(this);
      var serializedData = $form.serialize();
      $.post('./custSave', serializedData, function(responseText) {
          $('#res').html(responseText);
      });
  }
  ```
- Assuming there's data outside the form

  ```
  function saveCust(){
      $('#res').html('processing');
      var $form = $(this);
      var serializedData = $form.serialize() + "&id=" + $('#CustCode').val();
      $.post('./custSave', serializedData, function(responseText) {
          $('#res').html(responseText);
      });
  }
  ```

And you can even enhance this using more jQuery functions, but that's outside the scope of this answer.

Comment: You're welcome. If this post helps you to solve your problem, please mark it as the answer by clicking in the check below the rep points.